# Do the AfD need special protection for their events and leaders?

Tags: germany, fascism

The leaders of the German AfD party claim to be under attack. [Alice Weidel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Weidel) fled to Mallorca, and [Tino Chrupulla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tino_Chrupalla) claimed to have been attacked by an injection. They requested more protection of their events than other parties. Do they need such protection?

Comment: You should change your question to ask either, "have the AfD requested more police protection than other parties?" or "have the AfD received more police protection than other parties". These questions are answerable. Whether they "need" special protection is a matter of opinion and conjecture.

Comment: @CharlieEvans One could also ask under which circumstances protection is provided and if these circumstances likely apply here. I guess the answer is trying to answer that instead. Exchange need with "are entitled to".

Comment: Are AFD events not already more policed than other parties'?  I confess I don't really know much about them, but they have any large attendance by skinheads and counter-skinhead groups, they probably need more police already to keep the peace.

Comment: Please use the deletion process as defined by the rules of this community.

Comment: @Stančikas Stackoverflow did not let me delete the question.

Comment: Questions can't be deleted if they have upvoted answers, as those answers have value (even if the question itself may not) and should be allowed to stay. I understand that you object to some of the claims made in the answer, but that in itself is not a reason to delete the entire question - that's what comments and downvotes are for.

Comment: FWIW, I encourage you to denounce the AfD in any forum where that is appropriate. In the Q&A style of Politics SE, it is not. Here questions are asked, in a more or less neutral tone, and answers are given, in a more or less neutral tone. I do not believe Chrupalla, but I cannot prove he lied.

Comment: @o.m. The doctor said its only a description of the pain. The doctor said there was no needle puncture **AT ALL**. But you turn that thing. You say the doctor may found a needle puncture. You say the doctor may - he is not sure. Fuggin heal! Thats a lie. **Doctor sais said there is NO NEEDLE PUNCTURE AT ALL**! And you know that!

Answer (score 9):

You asked if they **need** more protection.

In Germany, the police provide protection to government *and opposition* politicians based on the role and an individual threat assessment. We cannot know what protection the AfD leadership **objectively needs** because facts are still unclear. We cannot know what the police has in the way of confidential information, either, because those who are cleared for it obviously cannot talk.

The typical level of protection for a state-level Secretary of the Interior seems to be two plainclothes-but-recognizable bodyguards (the radio earpieces and the haircuts tend to be a clue) and a driver. Secretaries of less exposed departments may have none. At the federal level, protection levels go up. During and after the Corona-related public health measures, the federal Secretary of Health got beefed-up protection ...

- Ms. Weidel claims to have gone into hiding after threats against her. She went to a popular tourist destination and supposedly she was seen in a beachfront restaurant.
- Mr. Chrupalla claims to have been attacked by an injection. His federal police bodyguards claim to have noticed nothing, a subsequent examination may have found a small puncture, a forensic examination of his blood [found nothing unusual](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/blutprobe-von-afd-politiker-chrupalla-ist-unaufaellig-19225161.html).

Emotions run high during the current state-level election campaigns, and the police decided, based on their threat assessment, to provide protection for various campaign events. It seems to me that [other parties](https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/innenpolitik/bayern-wahl-gruene-104.html) are more likely to be at risk (*from* AfD supporters).

It is common for the AfD to portray itself as the victim of persecution by all other parties and by 'the system.' It is common for all or most other parties to refuse to cooperate with the AfD in any way, even in ways which are *usually* parliamentary practice. Given this history, personally I take the AfD claims with a grain of salt.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a official source for the pucture during the subsequent examination?

Comment: @Grim, this one is 48h old, [tagesschau.de](https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/innenpolitik/chrupalla-ermittlungsstand-102.html). The question seems to be about a 'needle-like puncture' or a 'needle puncture.' The blood analysis found nothing.

Comment: @o.m. Thats a lie. Check your sources. The doctor pointed out that no needle-like puncture was found. (https://www.merkur.de/politik/zr-92563022.html)